# How to show a text when ForEach with a filter option shows no result in Swiftui?

Tags: filter, foreach, swiftui

I am trying to solve the following problem. I created a "List looking like " List with ForEach Loops. Which works just fine just not for one problem. In the last ForEach loop I would like to give a result in text if there is no result in the database "values". So if the ForEach loop does not go thru because there is no database set then I would like to give a Text result saying "0€".

Do you have any ideas?

Here the code:

```
ForEach(categories.filter({ (categories) -> Bool in
          categories.inOrOutCategory_ID == 1 }), id: \.category_ID) { categoryIndex in
            Section(header: Text("\(categoryIndex.category)")) {
              ForEach(subCategories.filter({ (subCategories) -> Bool in
                subCategories.category_ID == categoryIndex.category_ID }), id: \.subCategory_ID) {
                  subCategoryIndex in
                  HStack {
                    Text("\(subCategoryIndex.subCategory)").padding(.leading)
                    Spacer()
                    ForEach(values.filter({ (values) -> Bool in
                      values.subCategory_ID == subCategoryIndex.subCategory_ID && (values.month_ID == self.month && (values.year == self.year)) }), id: \.value_ID) { valueIndex in
                        
                        Text("\(String(format: "%.2f", valueIndex.value))€").padding(.trailing)
                    }
                  }
              }
            }
        }.padding(.leading)
```

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem today, the solution would be to create a method which would be true or false which checks the conditions of the filters manually then it will be necessary to create the view in swiftUI which is displayed if the method returns false (no result ) for example and in your view you display a text or whatever you want with no results

example :

```
func searchResult() -> Bool {
    if searchText == "" {
        return true // ne s'affiche pas
    }
    for u in subscribers{
        if u.firstname.contains(searchText){
             return true
        }
        if u.lastname.contains(searchText){
            return true
        }
    }
    return false // s'affiche
}
```

in you view :

```
                if !searchResult() {
                    Text("test")
                }
```